# Exibir Imagem no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho tabela feita no Javascript, segue a imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código do Javascript(Código está funcionando perfeitamente):

```
$(".js-tbody-historico-cliente").on("change", function() {
    var codigo_cliente = $(codigoCliente).val();
    var tipo_busca = $(tipoBusca).val();
    $
        .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/buscahistoricocliente",
            data: ({
                codigoCliente: codigo_cliente,
                tipoBusca: tipo_busca
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var text = "";

                text += "<thead><tr>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][0] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][1] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][2] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][3] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][4] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][5] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][6] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][7] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][8] + "</th>" +
                    "</thead>";
                for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text += "<tbody><tr>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][4] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][5] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][6] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][7] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][8] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][9] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][11] + "</td>" +
                        "</tr></tbody>";
                }
                $("#js-tbody-historico-venda-cliente").html(text);
                $("#graficosCliente").show();
            }
        });
});
```

Só que ao invés de aparecer o código do produto na coluna produto (como a imagem enviada) eu preciso que apareça imagem deste produto.

Coloquei Desta maneira, porém fiz algo errado e gostaria da ajuda dos colegas pois não tenho experiência com Js.

```
$(".js-tbody-historico-cliente").on("change", function() {
    var codigo_cliente = $(codigoCliente).val();
    var tipo_busca = $(tipoBusca).val();
    $
        .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/buscahistoricocliente",
            data: ({
                codigoCliente: codigo_cliente,
                tipoBusca: tipo_busca
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var text = "";

                text += "<thead><tr>" +
                if(data[0][0] == 'BS56EF'){
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src="BS56EF"/></th>" +
                }
                if(data[0][0] == 'FP56EA'){
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src="FP56EA"/></th>" +
                }
                 if(data[0][0] == 'FS56EB'){
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src="FS56EB"/></th>" +
                }
                 if(data[0][0] == 'FS56EB'){
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src="FS56EB"/></th>" +
                }



                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][1] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][2] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][3] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][4] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][5] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][6] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][7] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][8] + "</th>" +
                    "</thead>";
                for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text += "<tbody><tr>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][4] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][5] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][6] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][7] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][8] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][9] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][11] + "</td>" +
                        "</tr></tbody>";
                }
                $("#js-tbody-historico-venda-cliente").html(text);
                $("#graficosCliente").show();
            }
        });
});
```

O erro que apresenta é **Required String parameter 'parametroBuscaCliente' is not present**

Comment: Nao é a solução pro seu erro, mas você bagunçou um pouco na hora de fazer o `src`das imagens. Use aspas simples na string do javascript, e ai use aspas duplas ao redor do `src`da imagem. E não se esqueça de colocar a extensão do arquivo. Exemplo: `'<th class="text-center col-lg-1"> <img src="FS56EB.jpg"/></th>'`

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda e explicação, coloquei o código conforme o Paz comentou abaixo e agora vou procurar o porque o erro ocorre no Back. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Como o usuário [Máttheus Spoo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/110001/m%C3%A1ttheus-spoo) ressaltou, existe um erro de sintaxe na criação da sua table com imagem, quando você coloca 2 sinais `"` o javascript "entende" que você está fechando sua string, então para contornar isso você deve usar aspas simples, ou seja colocar nas partes de string do seu html que será inserido `'string aqui!'`.

Então seu código ficaria assim:

```
$(".js-tbody-historico-cliente").on("change", function() {
    var codigo_cliente = $(codigoCliente).val();
    var tipo_busca = $(tipoBusca).val();
    $
        .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/buscahistoricocliente",
            data: ({
                codigoCliente: codigo_cliente,
                tipoBusca: tipo_busca
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var text = "";

                text += "<thead><tr>" +
                if(data[0][0] == 'BS56EF'|| data[0][0] == 'FP56EA' || data[0][0] == 'FS56EB' || data[0][0] == 'FS56EB'){
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src='" + data[0][0] + ".png'/></th>" +
                }


                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][1] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][2] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][3] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][4] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][5] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][6] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][7] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][8] + "</th>" +
                    "</thead>";
                for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text += "<tbody><tr>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][4] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][5] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][6] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][7] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][8] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][9] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][11] + "</td>" +
                        "</tr></tbody>";
                }
                $("#js-tbody-historico-venda-cliente").html(text);
                $("#graficosCliente").show();
            }
        });
});
```

Porém como mencionado no comentário, esse exemplo resolve seu erro de imagem, mas não resolve o erro que você mencionou: "Required String parameter 'parametroBuscaCliente' is not present".

Esse é um erro de diferença de informação recebida pelo `backend`, ou seja ele espera um tipo de dados e você esta enviando outro tipo.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda até aqui, mais uma dúvida, no js eu não preciso colocar o caminho da imagem não? tenho uma pasta chamda imagens no projeto no qual eu salvei as imagens . Como a tabela foi feita no js e já é exibida pensei que deveria colocar o caminho da imagem no js .

Comment: porque que antes funcionava e agora não? pois essa tabela está sendo montada no js se eu voltar para o código antigo ele funciona e lista por código mais se colocar as imagens dar este erro.

Comment: Se as imagens estão dentro de uma pasta, tem sim que se referir ao caminho das mesmas. No caso então utilize `"<th class='text-center col-lg-1'> <img src='imagens/" + data[0][0] + ".png'/></th>" + `.
Sobre o erro, já tentou checar qual valor é atribuido para data[0][0]? talvez você descubra o que está ocorrendo. Só com esses dados não temos como descobrir.

Comment: O que eu estou ACHANDO é que, na hora de fazer o GET, você precisaria passar um terceiro parametro para poder pegar o valor de data[0][0], mas como não sabemos como está seu backend, não temos como ter certeza. Tente também inserir uma linha a chave parametroBuscaCliente dentro do objeto `data: `, e ponha algum valor válido dentro, veja o que ocorre.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Máttheus realmente vou ver aqui é algo no back .. trabalho com thymeleaf . agardeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui colocar as imagens em vez do código utilizando somente o javascript segue a resolução do problema,pois caso alguém esteja passando por algo semelhante possa solucionar.

```
 $(".js-tbody-historico-cliente").on("change", function() {
    var codigo_cliente = $(codigoCliente).val();
    var tipo_busca = $(tipoBusca).val();
    $
        .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/buscahistoricocliente",
            data: ({
                codigoCliente: codigo_cliente,
                tipoBusca: tipo_busca
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var text = "";

                text += "<thead><tr>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][0] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][1] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][2] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][3] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][4] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][5] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][6] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][7] + "</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center col-lg-1'>" + data[0][8] + "</th>" +
                    "</thead>";


                for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    text += "<tbody><tr>" +
                        "<td> <img src= /images/produtos/" + data[i][1] + ".png /></td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][4] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][5] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][6] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][7] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][8] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][9] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data[i][11] + "</td>" +
                        "</tr></tbody>";
                }
                $("#js-tbody-historico-venda-cliente").html(text);
                $("#graficosCliente").show();
            }
        });
});
```

no For acrescentei

```
"<td> <img src= /images/produtos/" + data[i][1] + ".png /></td>" +
```

no meu projeto eu tenho uma pasta images/produtos com todas as imagens que utilizo no projeto .